# Dialog crashes Mathematica

Tags: bugs, gui-construction, crash, dialog-window

I have some dialog windows in a GUI of which one regularly crashes the kernel. I managed to focus on this particular piece of code, though I don't really know what causes the crash:

```
CreateDialog[DialogNotebook[Button[TextCell["Go"], DialogReturn[]]]];
```

Whenever I push the button, *Mathematica* crashes. Strangly, if I remove either the `TextCell` wrapper or the `DialogReturn[]` command, the button behaves correctly. Any idea what is the cause of the symptom?

(*Mathematica* 8.0.4, Win7/64)

Comment: MM Support just provided me with a new binary on Monday that resolved crashing in 8.04 OS-X, and this works fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated:** It seems like this bug has been ironed out in version 9. as it does not cause a crash anymore.

---

Instead of comments, let's gather here the information we have:

- Crash happens on Mathematica 8.0.0.0 through 8.0.4, seemingly on all OS (reported confirmed on: WinXP/32, Mac OS 64-bit, Ubuntu 64bit, Win7/32).
- *Mathematica 7* doesn't crash, at least on Mac OS.
- MM Support provided R Hall a new Mac OS binary that fixes the crash on 8.0.4.